# Break sentence of a paragraph and dynamically rearrange and re frame

Tags: python

consider a paragraph,

```
p = "Both apples and oranges are fruits but apples are usually sweet and oranges are usually citrus.Apple have a pH arround 3 and orange between 3-4. Oranges are an excellent source of Vitamin C. Apples have a higher foliage (55mcg) as compared to oranges (23mcg).
```

I want to reframe the para like,

```
re_order = "Apple have a pH arround 3 and orange between 3-4.Both apples and oranges are fruits but apples are usually sweet and oranges are usually citrus.Apples have a higher foliage (55mcg) as compared to oranges (23mcg).Oranges are an excellent source of Vitamin C."
```

how transform `p` to `re_order` paragraph using python?

Comment: How to you want to re_order them ? By an alphanumerical sorting ? Why `            Apples have a higher foliage(55 mcg) as compared to oranges(23 mcg).` is the third in `re_order` ?

Comment: i just wanted to reorder the sentence in random. There is no conditions...is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to the `random.shuffle()` method. That is randomly mixing a list. 
Here an example:

```
# Import module
import random as rd

# Your string sentence
p = "Both apples and oranges are fruits but apples are usually sweet and oranges are usually citrus.Apple have a pH arround 3 and orange between 3-4. Oranges are an excellent source of Vitamin C. Apples have a higher foliage(55mcg) as compared to oranges(23mcg)."

# Slice p in list of sentence (every '.')
p_list = p.split(".")
print(p_list)
# ['Both apples and oranges are fruits but apples are usually sweet and oranges are
# usually citrus', 'Apple have a pH arround 3 and orange between 3-4', ' Oranges are an 
# excellent source of Vitamin C', ' Apples have a higher foliage(55mcg) as compared
# to oranges(23mcg)', '']

# Change the order
rd.shuffle(p_list)
print(p_list)
# [' Oranges are an excellent source of Vitamin C', ' Apples have a higher foliage(55mcg)
# as compared to oranges(23mcg)', '', 'Both apples and oranges are fruits but apples are 
# usually sweet and oranges are usually citrus', 'Apple have a pH arround 3 and orange 
# between 3-4']

# Rebuild the list as one string
p = '. '.join(p_list)
print(p)
# Oranges are an excellent source of Vitamin C.  Apples have a higher foliage(55mcg) as 
# compared to oranges(23mcg). . Both apples and oranges are fruits but apples are usually 
# sweet and oranges are usually citrus. Apple have a pH arround 3 and orange
# between 3-4
```

Comment: No the order changes every time you run the program. Sometimes, it may be possible that the order doesn't since it's randomly mixed and you are handling only 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

using random library in python3:

```
import random

def reorder(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.split('.')
    random.shuffle(phrase)

    return str.join('.', phrase) + '.'
```